# Storing array of objects in MySql database using PHP and laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a web app using PHP and laravel framework. I have the following class in my code.

```
class ReportField extends Model
{
    //
    public $name;
    public $quantity;
    public $unitCost;
    public $totalCost;
    public $estimation;
}
```

I write an array of these objects to a database using serialization.

```
$fieldsList=array();
foreach($items as $item){
        if($item->sale_type == 1){

                $reportField=new ReportField();
                $reportField->name=$item->item_name;
                $reportField->unitCost=$item->unit_cost;
                array_push($fieldsList,serialize($reportField));
         }
}

$gpForecast=new GPForecast();
$gpForecast->project_id=$project_id;
$gpForecast->fieldList=(serialize($fieldsList));
$gpForecast->save();
```

After unserialization now i want to convert those objects in array back to RecordField objects.

```
$gpForecast=GPForecast::all()->first(); //here i read one of array i write to database
$fieldList=unserialize($gpForecast->fieldList );
foreach($fieldList as $field){
       echo $field->name;
}
```

But then I get the error `Trying to get property of non-object` So how can I correct this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `protected $fillable` for your model attributes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `array_push($fieldsList,serialize($reportField)` I think is useless if You are doing `$gpForecast->fieldList=(serialize($fieldsList));`
 after itteration. This also probably cause thay you get empty entry - here:

`foreach($fieldList as $field){`

you are trying to get to serialized data

(here you serialize them: `array_push($fieldsList,serialize($reportField));`).

It means that you won't get `ReportField` object but probably serialized data.